# Reference javascript function within another script

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, wordpress

I'm having an 'end of day brain fart' & cannot get this simple piece of code to work. All I want to do is reuse a function in another script I am using.

For example, in javascript A I have:

```js
function rollLink(){
    //code that does something amazing
};
rollLink();
```

In another JS file (let's call it B), I am trying to reuse the `rollLink` function as part of a simple AJAX call:

```js
$.ajax({
    url: bla,
    data: bla,
    success:function(data) {
        $('#hero').append( data );
        rollLink();
    }
});
```

But I get an error saying **rollLink() is not defined**. Please can someone point out the error in my ways?

EDIT:

Ah sorry for the insufficient information. I shall elaborate:

- Script A is my main JS file. It runs on every page of my WP theme & is enqueued via the `functions.php` file.
- Script B is located within a WP plugin I am building.

Here is an example of the footer that is output:

```html
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/mytheme/javascripts/script_a.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/script_b.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is not enough information. Please also show us the way you load these two scripts.

Comment: that depends on in what order the scripts are loaded and how the code is executed.

Comment: Is `rollLink` global?  Also if the Ajax call is *really* fast, perhaps not all the scripts on the page have been loaded.

Comment: I think I've found the problem. Whilst when I enqueued the scripts I forgot to set the plugin to be at the bottom of the page (and thus below script A).

Comment: The issue I now have is that when I enqueue the script (referenced as B above) to appear at the bottom of the page, they are still called *before* my main script (above referenced as A). Hmmm, I think I need to do some further reading on how to enqueue scripts for WP plugins

Comment: @ChristianF, does the information I've added help?

Comment: I'm not sure script tags in the body have the same guarantee as in the head, where the second script will not get interpreted before the previous are completed. Can you try to move your two scripts to the head?

Comment: @Sheixt Please follow up on your question and tell us if you have found the answer.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I'm tied up with a few things at the moment. Will do my best to get back to this over the weekend.

Answer (score 0):

If the page a size is much greater than page b, it will take longer to download and execute. Worse, if you place your function at the button of the file, then page b will be ready, run and execute before even page a finishes loading. 
Just in case, try to validate if rollLink(); is a function before calling it.

```
    if(typeof rollLink === "function")
    {
      //true; 
    }
    else{
     //false;
    }
```

if true, mean the function is ready, otherwise, it doesn't exist (yet). 
Easy fix is to call your ajax function from the end of script where you make sure all required files are loaded.

A non efficient solution will be is to have recursive call to ajax function waiting for rollLink to load.

```
  if(typeof rollLink === "function")
        {
          //do ur work
        }
        else{
         //call again after one sec;
             setTimeout(function (){callSelfAjaxFunction();} , 1000);//every one sec

        }
```

So if you like that approach, you might want to pass a counter as a parameter increasing on each call and terminates when a exceeded so you won't have the function calling it self forever of the server is not available.

```
if(counter < 10 ){
  setTimeout(function (){
    callSelfAjaxFunction(counter++);
     } , 1000);//every one sec
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try wrapping `script_b.js` in a `$(document).ready`, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: bla,
        data: bla,
        success:function(data) {
            $('#hero').append( data );
            rollLink();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be because the file that uses the function is loaded before the file that is defining  that function. I had gone through the same problem when i was trying to load Image file and showing it on canvas the reason is that the file that is to be used is too large that it take much time for loading and the other file load before that file hence it says that the variable  are not defined.

### Solution:

What you can do is to make a Boolean variable funcionReady and initialize it as false and turn it value true inside the function's definition and before using that function check for the variable whether it is true or not if true then execute else wait.

Answer (score -3):

you should load both files on your page and file where you defined rollLink must be loaded before your ajax call. that's all in basic case.